# What are .sln and .vcproj files, and what do they contain?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new in the world of Visual Studio. Can somebody please explain what these two files contain? I know that one of them contains info about project, but what about the other one?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A project file `.vcproj / .vcxproj` contains settings on how to compile your code into a DLL or a binary file, or something else that the linker can assemble into one unit. A project file is just an xml file that contains compiler settings, linker settings, and describes which files you want to compile.

A solution file `*.sln`is a text file that groups together multiple project files.

So if you think of it like a tree, then you have got a good mental picture of it like this:

```
.sln
   .vcproj
      .h
      .h
      .cpp
      .cpp
   .vcxproj
      .h
      .h
      .cpp
      .cpp
   .csproj
      .cs
```

Comment: `*.vcxproj` is Visual Studio 2010 and above. `*.vcproj` is Visual Studio 2008 and below. How can a Visual Studio {2005|2008} solution contain a Visual Studio 2010 project file? Also see [Build System Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862524.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @jww Where the `x` stands for XML, similar to recent MS Office file formats.

Answer (score 14):

Solution files and project files are in an XML format and describe the parts of your projects and their relations, configurations and so on. In fact, both of these files are simply MSBuild scripts (which are run through MSBuild when, you guessed it, building your project.)

This means they are easy to manipulate by hand if needs be (though this should be a rare case) and also allows to add custom parts to the build script, create custom build scripts for MSBuild that can include the solution file, among other things, or just simple auto-build scripts that pass the solution file (or project) to MSBuild, say, on version control check-in.

The difference between solution files and project files is that a project file holds information specific to *that* project, unaware of its solution (though, Visual Studio will look up the hierarchy to an extent in an attempt find the relevant solution when opening a project, if one exists); the solution file is aware of all projects that are part of *that* solution and references each of them (such as a directory of files, if you like, but with projects), it also contains solution-wide information / configuration, that can be applicable to all projects within the solution.

As pointed out by Hans Passant, there is an exception: files for C++ projects pre-VS2010 are not XML MSBuild files, but are instead a [format documented by Microsoft on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: The .vcproj file is not an msbuild script.  Not until VS2010's .vcxproj

Comment: @Hans Passant: That useful information, I had no idea; I did a quick search and got [this reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2(v=VS.90).aspx) - thanks for the contribution.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but...   SLN files are not XML format. yes it is a text file but there are no XML elements in the file.

Answer (score 12):

A .vcproj file contains information about HOW to compile source to a target (mostly, an executable). In many cases, it is crucial to have the project file for successful compilation, so do not delete it. It is compareable to a .dsp file (Visual Studio 6), a .prj file (Borland compilers), or a Makefile (Unix, GNU compilers) and contains paths and compiler/linker command-line options.

A .sln file is merely a collection of multiple .vcproj files. As Visual Studio can automatically create one if not present, there is no need to keep it for distribution or archiving. It's the successor of a .dsw file (Visual Studio 6). Its name "Solution file" is IMHO misleading.

Comment: The solution files contain the manually configured inter-project build dependency tree, so you wouldn't want to delete a solution file that covered more than one project.

Comment: In other words, .dsp and .dsw files may be deleted in post-v6 versions, where .vcxproj and .sln are used instead.

Answer (score 7):

In short: one is for solution, and the other is for project, and a solution can contain multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows multiple projects in a solution. The data what projects are in a solution is in the sln (solution) file.