# what is the use of .CSProj and .Sln file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i searched a lot about **.csproj and .sln**. What i know now is .Csproj file contain info ab projects and .sln file contains info ab all the Projects in the solution.

My Question is what info does they contain any practical examples will really help.

And also is the below statement right ?

**We have .csproj in Web application not in website ?**

Thanks

Comment: Open them using Notepad and you will see :)

Comment: .csproject is for individual project. What ever changes you make with the project it is added in .csproject file. A .sln file is solution file it may contain more than one project.

Comment: See my edited answer regarding your question about website vs web project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are .sln and .vcproj files, and what do they contain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133796/what-are-sln-and-vcproj-files-and-what-do-they-contain)

Comment: This question is very constructive. I once dabbled during the mfc COM days and suddenly got thrown into the world of linux. Now, I am coming back to vstudio for some modules and have exactly have this kind of question in my mind what to open wither a .csproj or a .sln file. So my understanding now is that the .sln is the appropriate file that must be open. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 11):

What Habib said is the best thing for you to do. When you open a CSPROJ or SLN file you will find an XML file (stored as TEXT) with lots of information about

1. how to build a project and its settings.
2. the assemblies that the project references.
3. MSBuild information and commands: MSBuild is a framework to allow a developer to customize the build process using commands that they specify in MSBuild files such as the project files themselves. For example if you want the project to process files in a custom way everytime you build, you use MSBuild and you can put this in your CSProject file.

A web project has a references and also could have custom build operations, this is why there should be a project file for it. Also such a project contains files and the project file lists those files and how to build/compile them. This is unlike file based projects in other IDEs, in Visual Studio you can have files in the project folder that do *not* belong to the project.

Regarding your question about Websites and Web projects here's a link about [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) and regarding the inclusion of what files in a website (that *don't* have a project file) it says:

> For web site projects, all files in a folder structure are automatically considered to be included in the web site. If you want to exclude something from compilation, you must remove the file from the web site project folder or change its file-name extension to an extension that is not compiled and is not served by IIS.

Comment: Here's more on MSBuild: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx, tell us if you need more information.

Answer (score 5):

For the Solution (`.sln`) file contents, you can find a lot of information on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Concerning the Project (`.csproj`) file contents, [here is another MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2.aspx) that describes what's inside a C++ Visual Studio 2012 project, which is very close to a C# project, and here is an introduction to [Projects with Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s17bt45e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).