# Compiling and using multiple projects for a single solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I am attempting to build a very basic game engine. I would like to keep the Core part of the engine separate from the physics and rendering code. I know how to add the secondary Physics and Renderer projects to the main Core solution. But, how do I set up the relationship, and how do I access the Renderer and the Physics files in the Core part of the solution? Are there any necessary changes that I need to make to the project properties such as the Linker and VC++ Directories?

Answer (score 0):

```
<project name> (Core)
  <solution1> (Core project)
  <solution2> (Physics)
  <solution3> (Renderer)
```

In core project you want to use  Physics and Renderer. To link projects between them go to `Core project -> options -> common properties -> references -> add new reference -> check Physics and Renderer` after this make that setting from Linker and VC++ Directories (`C/C++ - > general -> additional include directories and  Linker - > general -> additional include directories` and `Linker - > general -> input -> additional dependencies`

Comment: Do I need to add the header files of the Physics and Renderer project to the VC++ directories? There are .lib files that I need to add to the Linker with respect to the Physics and Renderer projects? Am sorry, I am rather behind in terms of working with Visual Studio.

Comment: " Do I need to add the header files " - to Core project, yes : `C/C++ - > general -> additional include directories`- here you specify the location where you have the headers. " There are .lib files that I need to add to the Linker  " - if <solution2>  and < solution3>  are dlls, than yes, those dll's will create .lib and .dll . `Linker - > general -> additional include directories` - here you specify the folder where your lib is located., If < solution2> and <solution3> are not dlls, don't change anything at linker. Sorry if i was unclear. Ask anything.

Comment: look at this [What are .sln and .vcproj files, and what do they contain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133796/what-are-sln-and-vcproj-files-and-what-do-they-contain) where in my example .sln is <project name> and   .vcxproj is <solution1> and so on.